# How to split a string by space?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I need to split this string by space:

```
<i>Lorem</i> 1 <span class="text-danger">ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi consequuntur, eos? Error facere maiores minima molestiae obcaecati, quis voluptatum. Aspernatur cumque doloremque ducimus eos explicabo facilis fuga, nulla quos voluptate.
```

The difficulty is that I also have html tags inside.

I tried something like this, but it takes spaces as well

```
/<(.*?)>(.*?)<(.*?)>|\w*(.*?)(?:\s*?[,?.-])?/g
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you also want to split `span class` or should it maintain together?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to extract an element, use a selector or document parser.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex, [it's really a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239), use a DOM parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we might not want to use regular expressions. But, if you really have to, I'm guessing that we could use space in a capturing group `(\s)` and than would likely work:

```js
const regex = /(\s)/gm;
const str = `<i>Lorem</i> 1 <span class="text-danger">ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi consequuntur, eos? Error facere maiores minima molestiae obcaecati, quis voluptatum. Aspernatur cumque doloremque ducimus eos explicabo facilis fuga, nulla quos voluptate.
`;
const subst = `\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```